# Why does my PHP Google app engine not connect to Google cloud sql?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my Google app engine PHP app to Google cloud sql via unix socket (I assume that is correct so that I don't have to connect to the ip). The connect via IP works but the unix socket does not. Any ideas? It's also weird that when I ssh into the box, I don't see any `/cloudsql/` directory. I actually don't see even my `index.php` on there but the page loads fine, maybe debug mode means something else?

I'm using:

```
$db = new pdo(
  'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/testproject-xxxxxx:us-central1:library;dbname=books',
  'phpapp',  // username
  'somepw'       // password
);
```

And get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

Comment: Hey @Nighthawk did you solve this?

Comment: For anybody who happens to come across this: the filesystem in a GAE app is dynamic, so you might not see anything in the /cloudsql directory if you shell in and do `ls`; it's created when you open the connection for reading or writing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was adding this section to the app.yaml:

`beta_settings:
      cloud_sql_instances: "<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>"`